# What wrong with the following code?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a 20*120 matrix. For each column in the matrix I need to find the maximum value between all the values, and then sum the remaining values. Then I need to divide the maximum value by the summation of the remaining values. I  tried the following code but the result was not correct. What is the problem?

```
s = 1:z      %z=120
for i = 1:x       %x=20
    maximss = max(Pres_W);     %maximum value
    InterFss = (sum(Pres_W))-maximss;     %remaining values
    SIRk(:,s) = (maximss(:,s))./(InterFss(:,s));
end
```

Comment: This is not valid MATLAB code. Also, what do we know about `Pres_W`? Can it have repeating values? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Dev-iL, this is valid MATLAB code.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Almost, but not quite. It's missing a `for` keyword. Even though it might be an honest copy-pasting mistake, I'd really like OPs to pay attention to what they upload. For this reason I also did not correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of answering "what's wrong", I'll first provide a solution explaining how this *should* be done:

Say we have an example matrix `m` as follows:

```
m =    
    8    5    9   14   10    7    5
   10    8   12   11    9    9   12
   10    3    7    7    8    4    6
   13   11    6   15   13   11    9
```

Find the maximum value of each column:

```
col_max = max(m, [], 1)
col_max =    
   13   11   12   15   13   11   12
```

Sum all elements in each column, and substract the maximum values:

```
col_sum = sum(m, 1) - col_max
col_sum =    
   28   16   22   32   27   20   20
```

Divide the maximum value by the sum of the other elements:

```
col_max ./ col_sum
ans =    
   0.46429   0.68750   0.54545   0.46875   0.48148   0.55000   0.60000
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
max(m,[],1)./(sum(m,1)-max(m,[],1))
ans =
   0.46429   0.68750   0.54545   0.46875   0.48148   0.55000   0.60000
```

---

By the way: Your code does exactly what you're explaining, it returns the maximum value divided by all values except the maximum value.

---

**Notes regarding best practice:**

Vectorize things like this, no need for loops.

`max(m, [], 1)` is the same as `max(m)` for 2D-arrays. However, if your matrix for some reason only have one row, it will return the maximum value of the row, thus a single number.

`sum(m,1)` is the same as `sum(m)` for 2D-arrays. However, if your matrix for some reason only have one row, it will return the sum of the row, thus a single number.